# расширение tpl файла в phpstorm автокомплит не работает

Tags: php, phpstorm, tpl

расширение tpl файла не распознает IDE phpstorm для автокомплита, приходиться  набирать функций и какие-либо конструкции в ручную

а вот js и php расширения безукоризненно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках `Settings/Editor/FileTypes/` выбираем расширение PHP и затем кликаем на плюсик, чтобы добавить расширение `*.tpl` и всё!